# Uploading files to FTP server with wininet

Tags: c++, ftp

So, I got a problem with uploading a text file to an ftp server. My code looks like this:

```
HINTERNET hInternet = InternetOpen(NULL, INTERNET_OPEN_TYPE_DIRECT, NULL, NULL, 0);
HINTERNET hFtpSession = InternetConnect(hInternet, "habubabu.cba.pl", INTERNET_DEFAULT_FTP_PORT, "myusername", "mypassword", INTERNET_SERVICE_FTP, INTERNET_FLAG_PASSIVE, 0);
FtpPutFile(hFtpSession, "file.txt", "/papaj/file.txt", FTP_TRANSFER_TYPE_ASCII, 0);

InternetCloseHandle(hFtpSession);
InternetCloseHandle(hInternet);
return 0;
```

Anyway,when I try to execute it, and then check if the file was actually uploaded to ftp server, it does not work.

I have tried basic error handling with if statements,GetLastError,etc.

The file that i want to upload is in the same directory as compiled C++ source code.I want to upload the file to a folder called "papaj" which is inside my ftp server.I would appreciate any help.

EDIT:I have done what you guys suggested,and it worked(I mean,i just accidentally misspelled filename).Thanks a lot <3 .

Comment: What do you mean exactly by "it does not work"?

Comment: I mean,the expected txt file does not exists on ftp server after program execution. While error handling,it told me that the file cannot be found,but i have added a proper name with extension and i have putted it in the same folder on my pc as the program itself

Comment: So it seems like this problem has little to do with FTP or a server or WinInet, and more to do with path handling in your C++ program. Are you sure that "the same folder on my pc as the program itself" is also the _current working directory_ for the process? You can test this with a simple `std::ifstream::open` attempt. Remove the FTP code from your testcase until you've proven that the file opening bit works. Divide and conquer!

Comment: The local file `file.txt` must be in "exec" path, not in source path. or use an absolute path `D:\\myprogram\\...\\file.txt`